# Can you tell me if my Father, a Lt Colonel, was paid during WW2?

Tags: world-war-two, united-kingdom

Can you tell me if my Father, a Lt Colonel, was paid during active service in the Middle East and Europe, and if so how much and was the pay given to his spouse in England or direct to the officer ?

Comment: Welcome to History, Bill Grover! Please take the [tour] and read the [help] center. What has your research shown you so far? Where have you already searched? Please help us to help you. You may improve your question to comply with site guidelines with an edit and the help of [ask].

Comment: Considering how bureaucratic the military is, there should be a set of regulations for the pay of officers serving in foreign lands and who the pay was supposed to be sent to.  And depending on various factors it is even possible that there might be surviving records of some or all of the payments.   You need advice from someone familiar with British military records.

Comment: [This site](https://www.forces-war-records.co.uk/records.asp?SE=go&adID=248561209874&KW=army%20service%20%2Brecords%20ww2&SC=32&NO=5973&gclid=Cj0KCQiA5aTUBRC2ARIsAPoPJk8IjejItpv9RGILWu7rU-k6IHlpM6f8Bt9L282dvgYKwOHGdQgzAyoaAlddEALw_wcB) might be a place to start.

Answer (score 6):

The rates of pay were increased at least twice during the war, but from July 1940 to at least March 1944, a Lieutenant Colonel's pay was 43 shillings per day, which is equivalent to about £110,000 per year in 2017 money. There were additional allowances for family members.

Soldiers with dependents were expected to allocate some of their pay to them, and there was a system for making those payments in the UK. The amount would have been up to the soldier, at least for officers. The balance was available to the soldier, and they would often draw it in local currency if serving overseas.

Source: [Hansard report of a question in Parliament](http://hansard.millbanksystems.com/commons/1940/jul/30/pay-and-allowances#S5CV0363P0_19400730_HOC_153), but the OCR has not made a good job of the layout. Conversion by [Measuring Worth](https://www.measuringworth.com/index.php), using their labour value scale.